# referencing and Label

Tags: cross-referencing, back-referencing

I use \label{} and \ref{} to refer the reader to a reference in biblio, but when I excute the result of refering is as in image, it give me [2(b)3] and I need just [3]. How can I solve this problem ??
[image: ref1[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtrIo.png)

Comment: you should use `\cite` not `\ref` to reference a bibitem (no `\label` is needed)

Comment: Thanks its work with \cite. Is there any commande for colors ??

Comment: @FouadEl -- Please clarify what you mean by "is there any commande for colors". E.g., what is supposed rendered in color (and in which color)?